# Entity relationship diagram software

Tags: database

I'm looking for a tool that generates DB diagrams.

- Free (open source maybe)
- Works in Linux (cross-platform maybe)
- Supports PostgreSQL/MySQL

Answer (score 30):

[diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net) is free and [on Github](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio) (I work on the project). It does work on Linux and has a generic SQL import, under Arrange->Insert->SQL.

You can save either locally, or directly to Google Drive, OneDrive or Dropbox. There's also a [Desktop version](https://get.diagrams.net) available.

[image: ER shapes in draw.io]

Comment: I've used and liked the online version of Draw IO to create several diagrams.

Comment: Can we import SQL from PostgreSQL or only from MSSQL and MySQL? Thanks!

Comment: @Ignacio Answering for future audiences, that yes, we can. I imported redshift(derived from PostgreSQL) DDL scripts and it worked flawlessly (1 out of 20 required minor manual editing).

Answer (score 16):

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) is a good tool for working with its namesake that does ERD modeling. I've used it on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for an entity relationship model (not relational model) you have to try Dia http://dia-installer.de/

This software works on linux/windows/mac. And have a branch on git.

The entity relationship model has the purpose of make a model of the problem and let you understand the problem, so in the end you can generate a good relational model to have the most efficient model for you database.

This software is not intended to generate mysql tables directly but it has a plugin to convert Dia diagrams to sql, you can check it out in the same [link](http://dia-installer.de/parse-dia-sql/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try [PowerArchitect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect)
It's Java based (therefor cross-platform) and I have used it successfully with PostgreSQL

If you do want to spent some money (albeit not much), have a look at [DbWrench](http://www.dbwrench.com) which offers more features than PowerArchitect

Another open source/cross-platform option is [Mogwai ERDesigner](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/). Although there is one thing that I really don't like about it: if requires a connection to a database (to validate/define datatypes) which I find a very limiting requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Software Ideas Modeler](https://www.softwareideas.net/en/erd-tool) for entity relationship diagrams. It could meet your requirements - it's not open source but it has a free version, it works in Linux via Mono and it supports MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some software to auto generate ER diagram from existing database then you will love this tool: http://schemaspy.org/

Answer (score 0):

https://drawerd.com is a online database structure tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

zenchart is an online ER model generation tool, which can generate ER models through database DDL scripts, support exporting SQL, and the relationship between tables.

https://www.zenchart.net/erd-index.html